# What does the column number signify in ORA errors

Tags: sql, oracle

What does the column number signify in ORA errors?

For example below Error report says:-

```
ORA-06550: line 67, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 67, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Here I understand that **Line 67** means there is an issue at line 67 of the PL/SQL script, but what does **column 13** signify here, just curious how it can help me to identify the issue.

At line no 67, I have this line of code(`BK1 := 48715788;`):-

```
begin
    BK1 := 48715788;
```

The variable BK1 is declared collection type as:-

```
BK1 userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER;
```

And TYPE_TABNUMBER declared as:-

```
create or replace TYPE    "TYPE_TABNUMBER"      as table of number  ;
```

Comment: Chararacter no 13, in the row. (Space character is also counted.)

Comment: @jarlh, does it also count the spaces(query with indentation)?

Comment: Yes, space is counted. See it as a checkered block.

Comment: @jarlh, I added the code which is at line 67, So it would be starting position of the number **4**8715788?

Comment: And the BK1 data type is?

Comment: My bad, @jarlh, it is declared as a collection datatype which is defined as `create or replace TYPE  "TYPE_TABNUMBER"      as table of number  ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORA-06550: line 67, column 13:` means the 67th row and the 13th character in the row.

To put the error messages:

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 67, column 13:
> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> ORA-06550: line 67, column 5:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

into an equivalent English sentence:

> The expression `48715788` (starting at column 13 of line 67) is of the wrong type (to perform the assignment operation); this means that the statement `BK1 := 48715788;` (starting at column 5 of line 67) has been ignored.

As for your error:

```sql
DECLARE
    BK1 userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER;
begin
    BK1 := 48715788;
```

You should initialise the collection with the number as part of the collection (rather than trying to assign a number to a collection variable):

```sql
DECLARE
    BK1 userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER;
begin
    BK1 := userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER(48715788);
```

or:

```sql
DECLARE
    BK1 userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER;
begin
    BK1 := userDefined.TYPE_TABNUMBER();
    BK1.EXTEND();
    BK1(BK1.COUNT) := 48715788;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yhj9dq69)